# Visual Studio uses UserControlDesigner instead of CustomDesigner

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, custom-server-controls

I've got an ASP-UserControl `QuestionWithAnswer (.ascx) : BaseQuestion : UserControl`
and a ControlDesigner `QuestionDesigner : UserControlDesigner`.
Now i use the DesignerAttribute to associate control and designer:

```
[Designer(typeof(QuestionDesigner))]
public class BaseQuestion : UserControl
```

all types are in the same assembly (WEB Application).
But it still loads UserControlDesigner instead of mine.
Did i have to put my designer in a seperate assembly?
I suppose the asp-page designer cannot find the designer.

thx!
mo

---

demo code:

```
public class FragenDesigner : UserControlDesigner
{
    private DesignerActionList _actionList;
    private DesignerVerb[] _verbs;

    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists
    {
        get
        {
            if (_actionList == null)
            {
                _actionList = new DesignerActionList(new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox());
                _actionList.AutoShow = true;


                ActionLists.Add(_actionList);
            }
            return base.ActionLists;
        }
    }

    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_verbs == null)
            {
                _verbs = new DesignerVerb[]
                         {
                             new DesignerVerb("test", onblabla), 
                         };

                Verbs.AddRange(_verbs);
            }

            return base.Verbs;
        }
    }

    private void onblabla(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("blabla");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

okay there is already an answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.usercontroldesigner.aspx.

> **Remarks**
>
> There is no developer advantage to
>   creating your own designer derived
>   from UserControlDesigner. To enhance
>   the design-time experience for a
>   custom control, derive your control
>   from CompositeControl and your
>   designer from
>   CompositeControlDesigner. In that
>   case, you would not use an .ascx file
>   for your ASP.NET markup.

In my case there is no possibility to change to CompositeControls.
Trust me, i prefer Composite/WebControls ...